# 2000 IMOSL N6- set of positive integers that cannot be written as sum of distinct perfect square is finite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Show that the set of positive integers that cannot be represented as a sum of distinct perfect squares is finite.
I've tried possibly everything I could and figured out that this would be true only for some small numbers, and after running some code got that 116 is the last element of the set.
Any hints from here on?
I checked online and got a solution from prase.cz but wasn't able to comprehend that.

Comment: Surely the idea is do induction and invoke the greedy algorithm.  That is, given some number $n$, subtract off the greatest square less than $n$ and argue that the new number is in the range of the induction hypothesis. Just play with the numbers until you get a range for which this argument works.  It has to be a little messy since there are counterexamples, after all.

Comment: [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Numbers_not_Sum_of_Distinct_Squares#:~:text=The%20positive%20integers%20which%20are,96%2C108%2C112%2C128) is an argument along those lines.  I note that they take out a square below the largest possible, contrary to my guess.  This is because you don't want a square so close that the difference is on the bad list.

Comment: Kalva's solution (mirror site prase) is a good one to look at and work through. You just need to show it for "large enough N". Kalva's idea is to consider $n = 116k + r$, and show that for each $r$, there is a large enough $K$ so that 1) $116K+r$ can be written as sum of distinct odd squares, 2) $116(k-K)$ can be written as sum of distinct even squares.  $\quad$ This avoids the "prove that it could be done for $n = 128 $ to some large enough number like in lulu's link. $\quad$ I won't be surprised if we can just consider $ n = 9k+r$, and proceed with a large enough $k$.